# Can I use Mathematica and the Google BigQuery API

Tags: api

I would like to query a large public dataset hosted in Google BigQuery using the Google BigQuery API.  I notice there are client libraries for C#, Go, Java, PHP, Python, and Ruby along with examples at
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries
but I don't see anything Mathematica-specific. Is there a way to interface the Google BigQuery API with Mathematica?  Any pointers/examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can try making your own connection. This could either be done using `URLRead` in a somewhat fragile manner or by creating a custom connection using the service connection framework. I have made many connections with `ServiceConnect` and have found they treat me well.